# Кастомизация progress bar с помощью <shape>

Tags: android, вёрстка, progress-bar

Привет! Пытаюсь кастомизировать progress bar, используя `<shape>`. Требуется сделать его в таком же стиле (с нижним отступом): [image: flat button example]
Создавал кнопки с таким же эффектом, используя следующий xml код для `android:background` параметров кнопки (все работало):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/btn_color_bottom"  />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/btn_color_top" />
        <padding android:bottom="6dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Но для progress bar  с целью изменения его цвета и формы в `android:progressDrawable` требуется указывать подобные параметры в xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/color1" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/color2" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Поэтому вышеизложенные параметры для кнопки не подойдут сюда. Пробовал делать так, используя `<padding android:bottom="integer"/>` но безрезультатно (показывается только передний цвет, без внутренней тени):

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/color1_bottom" />
        </shape>

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:bottom="5dp" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/color1_top" />
        </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/color2_bottom" />
        </shape>

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:bottom="5dp" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/color2_top" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Как я могу добиться такого эффекта (фигура с нижней внутренней тенью) в отображении progress bar, не используя изображений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге создал два progress bar: один позади другого. Задал соответствующие цвета и заставил отображать одни и те же данные. Получился требуемый эффект.